# Get the value of checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

So I've got code that looks like this:

```
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="3" name="mailId[]">
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="mailId[]">
```

I just need Javascript to get the value of whatever checkbox is currently checked.

**EDIT**: To add, there will only be ONE checked box.

Comment: Why not use radio button?

Comment: Because I'm writing a plugin for a site

Comment: If you need only one checkbox, why don't you use radio buttons? this is the more suitable UI component for this job.

Comment: @TalYaron Can you deselect a radio buttons ? I think not without js code. Maybe the OP want to deselect the box easily.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

*For modern browsers*:

```
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked').value;
```

*By using `jQuery`*:

```
var checkedValue = $('.messageCheckbox:checked').val();
```

*Pure javascript without `jQuery`*:

```
var checkedValue = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
      }
}
```

Comment: @Mageek it's bad practice to add same id on multiple elements.

Comment: @Engineer No, just putting a different id for each checkbox.

Comment: @Mageek There will be no benefits.

Comment: @Engineer "Saving bytes" because we must simply write `document.getElementById("foo").value();` and "saving calculations" because `getElementById` is surely speedier than `getElementsByTagName` and a loop.

Comment: @Mageek Yes, `document.getElementById` is faster, but you should perform as much `document.getElementById` calls,as there are checkboxes, and *which even worse*, you **have to hardcode all the ids in your script**.

Comment: for jQuery `.is(":checked")` is the correct way as `.val()` will return the attribute value if its defined.. and even if its not defined it will return "on" and not a boolean value.. http://jsfiddle.net/d5f7wnzu/

Comment: I think what @Mageek is saying is that if you have a huge page (imagine a huge table with 100000000 rows and columns :) inside), the selector ".messageCheckbox:checked" may loop inside every cell of it to search for checkboxes, even if there is none anywhere (at least on older browsers it sure did). Using ids is usually faster, so you may put a single div with an id like "#checkboxesarehere" around them and use document.querySelector('#checkboxesarehere .messageCheckbox:checked') to limit the search to that area of the document. Of course here is just an example so I'd leave it as it is.

Comment: @FrancescoMM If you have millions of input cells, then your UI sucks. There is no need to show millions of input boxes, that the client will fill on his/her entire life. It would be better to think about the changing the UI ;)

Comment: @Engineer agreed indeed, but who talked about a million of input boxes? A .messageCheckbox selector will search in every div, in every td, in every dom node of any kind... Even if you have only one checkbox.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked').value` generates TypeError if no checkbox is checked

Comment: This blows up - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Might want to add that in the vanilla JS case `.checked` returns a `boolean`, `true`/`false`.

Comment: This code work for me:
        var items = [];
 var checkedValue = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked'); 
 for (var i = 0; i < checkedValue.length; i++) {
  items.push(checkedValue[i].value);
 }
 alert(items);

Answer (score 368):

None of the above worked for me but simply use this:

```
document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox').checked;
```

Comment: I concur. You confirmed what I thought. I like to put var chk1= document.getElementById('messageCheckbox');
That way I can reference the "chk1" variable's properties: checked, enabled, style, etc.

Comment: Where did you get that `id`? Can you please explain? The guy who asked the question used `class` in the input actually. It will be good if you can provide the full code so I can understand from where you got the `id`

Comment: This can't work with the example code provided by OP... I'm curious why it got so many upvotes while not answering the question, although a quick fix might make it right.

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Comment: surprised how this answer got many votes!! it is bad practice to use same id for multiple times in a page

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan probably people like me (not using id for multiple items) wondering why .value was giving them undefinied.

Answer (score 141):

I am using this in my code.Try this

```js
var x=$("#checkbox").is(":checked");
```

If the checkbox is checked `x` will be true otherwise it will be false.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but can be used to determine whether or not a checkbox is checked. +1 since it still helped me out.

Comment: Does not answer the question but is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Useful when `#checkbox` is a variable, e.g. `myCheckbox`.

Comment: Yes ```.is(":checked")``` help me thanks bro

Answer (score 26):

in plain javascript:

```js
function test() {
    var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('mailId[]');
    var len = cboxes.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        alert(i + (cboxes[i].checked?' checked ':' unchecked ') + cboxes[i].value);
    }
}
```

```js
function selectOnlyOne(current_clicked) {
    var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('mailId[]');
    var len = cboxes.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        cboxes[i].checked = (cboxes[i] == current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

*This does not directly answer the question, but may help future visitors.*

---

If you want to have a variable always be the current state of the checkbox (rather than having to keep checking its state), you can modify the `onchange` event to set that variable.

This can be done in the HTML:

```
<input class='messageCheckbox' type='checkbox' onchange='some_var=this.checked;'>
```

or with JavaScript:

```
cb = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox')[0]
cb.addEventListener('change', function(){some_var = this.checked})
```

Comment: As a future visitor I can confirm that it helps.

Answer (score 7):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ckbox = $("input[name='ips']");
  var chkId = '';
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    
    if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
      $("input[name='ips']:checked").each ( function() {
      chkId = $(this).val() + ",";
        chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);
    });
       
       alert ( $(this).val() ); // return all values of checkboxes checked
       alert(chkId); // return value of checkbox checked
    }     
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="ips" value="12520">
<input type="checkbox" name="ips" value="12521">
<input type="checkbox" name="ips" value="12522">
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
alert($(".messageCheckbox").is(":checked").val())
```

This assumes the checkboxes to check have the class "messageCheckbox", otherwise you would have to do a check if the input is the checkbox type, etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" onchange="getValue(this.value)" value="3" name="mailId[]">

<input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" onchange="getValue(this.value)" value="1" name="mailId[]">
```

```
function getValue(value){
    alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me without throwing errors in the console when the box wasn't checked so I did something along these lines instead (onclick and the checkbox function are only being used for demo purposes, in my use case it's part of a much bigger form submission function):

```js
function checkbox() {
  var checked = false;
  if (document.querySelector('#opt1:checked')) {
     checked = true;
  }
  document.getElementById('msg').innerText = checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkbox()" id="opt1"> <span id="msg">Click The Box</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use following ways via `jQuery` or `JavaScript` to check whether `checkbox` is clicked.

```
$('.messageCheckbox').is(":checked"); // jQuery
document.getElementById(".messageCheckbox").checked //JavaScript
```

To obtain the value checked in jQuery:

```
$(".messageCheckbox").is(":checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprised to see no working vanilla JavaScript solutions here (the top voted answer does not work when you follow best practices and use different IDs for each HTML element). However, this did the job for me:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[name='mailId']:checked"),0).map(function(v,i,a) { 
      return v.value; 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you using after an event occurred you can use

```js
const selected = event.target.checked; //true or false
```

An example would be if you want to track selected items, here is an example using react react-hook-form react material ui, it would be better than using `value` from rendered `field` that give wrong values

```js
...
const [selectedQuestions, setSelectedQuestions] = useState(0);

const handleSelectedQuestions = (checked) => {
  if (checked) {
    setSelectedQuestions((prev) => prev + 1);
  } else {
    setSelectedQuestions((prev) => prev - 1);
  }
};

<Controller
  key={item.id}
  control={control}
  name={`question-${item.id}`}
  defaultValue={false}
  render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
    <Grid key={item.id} item xs={12}>
      <QuestionCard
        item={item}
        handleOpen={handleOpen}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        isError={isError}
        onChange={(event) => {
          handleSelectedQuestions(event.target.checked);
          onChange(event);
        }}
      />
    </Grid>
  )}
/>
...
```

```js
export default function QuestionsCard({ item, handleOpen, onChange }) {
  return (    
    ...
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          // checked={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          sx={{
            '& svg': {
              fontSize: '1.266rem',
            },
          }}
        />
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: @herrstrietzel, it was about javascript the first line answer the question then the second code is how to use the first code in react and I have mentioned this too react, react hook form, react material ui

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com), `data` is passed as the second parameter to the `onChange` event.

You can therefore access the `checked` property as follows:

```html
<Checkbox label="Conference" onChange={(e, d) => console.log(d.checked)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values of all checkboxes using jQuery, this might help you. This will parse the list and depending on the desired result, you can execute other code. BTW, for this purpose, one does not need to name the input with brackets []. I left them off.

```
  $(document).on("change", ".messageCheckbox", function(evnt){
    var data = $(".messageCheckbox");
    data.each(function(){
      console.log(this.defaultValue, this.checked);
      // Do something... 
    });
  }); /* END LISTENER messageCheckbox */
```

Answer (score 0):

*pure javascript and modern browsers*

```js
// for boolean
document.querySelector(`#isDebugMode`).checked

// checked means specific values
document.querySelector(`#size:checked`)?.value ?? defaultSize
```

### Example

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="isDebugMode"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="size"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  document.querySelector(`form`).onsubmit = () => {
    const isDebugMode = document.querySelector(`#isDebugMode`).checked
    const defaultSize = "10"
    const size = document.querySelector(`#size:checked`)?.value ?? defaultSize
    //  for defaultSize is undefined or null
    // const size = document.querySelector(`#size:checked`)?.value
    console.log({isDebugMode, size})
    return false
  }
</script>
```

- [Optional_chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a more simpler approach

```
const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="mailId[]"]:checked')).map((p) => p.value);
```

Answer (score -7):

In my project, I usually use this snippets:

```
var type[];
$("input[name='messageCheckbox']:checked").each(function (i) {
                type[i] = $(this).val();
            });
```

And it works well.

Comment: An extremely inefficient way of doing that.