# Show/Display the checked checkbox value using PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

I thought if it is possible to get this done with PHP or JavaScript:

Let's say I have two checkboxes:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="Tuesday" value="111"/> Tueday</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday" value="112"/> Wednesday</li>
```

I want to see the value of the `checked="checked"` which is **111** after the page is loaded.

How can i achieve this? If this is possible in PHP and JavaScript, I would like to have both methods. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the checkbox within a form or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of **[Get the value of checked checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599666/get-the-value-of-checked-checkbox)**.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['Tuesday'])) echo $_POST['Tuesday'];`

Comment: You will have no method with php "after the page is loaded" !

Comment: with `jQuery` you can just use `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var ch = document.getElementsByName('Tuesday')[0];
    if(ch.checked)
        // use ch.value
});
```

Or if you want to display checked values:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var checkedValues= [];
    var chs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < chs.length; i++)
        if(chs[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox' && chs[i].checked)
            checkedValues.push(chs[i].value);
    // use checkedValues
});
```