# Get value of multiple comboboxes

Tags: javascript

I'm very inexperienced with little coding knowledge, but...

I'm looking to get the value of 3 comboboxes, so when the customer clicks on combobox one and selects the value, it will increase the price in textbox or similiar. Same for the other 2, it will increase the price and they can see what the price will be before adding it to the basket - hope this makes sense.

I just don't know where to start with this so either a pointer or offer would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: Take a look at some Javascript tutorial first. http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: At least the HTML code could be provided to add the Javascript needed

Comment: As @Alvaro told, take a look at the tutorial and cook some code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start by looking at how [inputs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) & [checkboxes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp) are described in HTML.

Then you'll want to [get their values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599728/3984553) using javascript.

From there you'll want to add each value, then [display the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554171/3984553) formatted as [currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript).