# Javascript getElementsByTagName("input").value not returning results

Tags: javascript, validation, categories

We have one page with process and matched subprocess listed based dynamically based on process selection. Process can have more than one selection. Based on process selection sub process will be loaded.

Here I need to validate max only one subprocess needs to be selected for each process.

I am trying to achieve that with below validation. Not getting values on  `checkboxProcess[i].value()` tried with `InnerText` and also `InnerHtml`

```js
function Validate() {
  var atLeast = 1;
  var CHKcblProcess = document.getElementById("cblProcess");
  var checkboxProcess = CHKcblProcess.getElementsByTagName("input");
  //var listOfSpans = checkboxProcess.getElementsByTagName('span');
  var counter = 0;
  var subcounter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxProcess.length; i++) {

    if (checkboxProcess[i].checked) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  if (atLeast > counter) {
    alert("Please select atleast " + atLeast + " Process item(s)");
    return false;
  } else {
    var CHKcblSubProcess = document.getElementById("cblSubDept");
    var checkboxSubProcess = CHKcblSubProcess.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var subcounter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxProcess.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxProcess[i].checked) {
        alert(checkboxProcess[i].innerText);
        counter++;
      }
    }
    /*for (var i = 0; i < checkboxProcess.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxProcess[i].checked) {
          alert(checkboxProcess[i].value());
          counter++;
          for (var i = 0; i < checkboxSubProcess.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxSubProcess[i].checked) {
              subcounter++;


            }
          }
        }
      }*/

    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="cblProcess" border="0" style="font-size:X-Small;">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_0" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$0\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_0">Additive Manufacturing</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_1" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$1" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$1\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_1">Assembly</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_2" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$2" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$2\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_2">Component M/C</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_3" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$3" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$3\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_3">Compounding Extrusion Finishing</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_4" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$4" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$4\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_4">Custom Tool M/C</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_5" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$5" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$5\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_5">Digital Factory</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_6" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$6" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$6\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_6">Energy</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_7" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$7" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$7\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_7">Molding</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_8" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$8" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$8\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_8">Plating</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblProcess_9" type="checkbox" name="cblProcess$9" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblProcess$9\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="cblProcess_9">Stamping</label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="cblSubDept" border="0" style="font-size:X-Small;">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="cblSubDept_0" type="checkbox" name="cblSubDept$0" /><label for="cblSubDept_0">[Assembly] - Connector Assembly</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblSubDept_1" type="checkbox" name="cblSubDept$1" /><label for="cblSubDept_1">[Assembly] - PSP</label></td>
    <td><input id="cblSubDept_2" type="checkbox" name="cblSubDept$2" /><label for="cblSubDept_2">[No Sub-Dept]</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="btnInquiry" value="Submit" onclick="return Validate(); id=" btnInquiry " class="NavButton-medium " />
```

Comment: Where is that JS code in relation to the HTML?  Is it in the `head` of the document, or somewhere in the `body`?

Comment: You have to do `checkboxProcess.value`. `.value` is a property, so no parenthesis after it. `.innerText` will return any text that current element has in it. Since its a checkbox, it does not have any. So goes with `.innerHTML`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of checked checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599666/get-the-value-of-checked-checkbox)

Comment: check the console there is an error 
`js:41 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: onclick="return Validate(); <-- missing a closing `"` guessing that is a typo?

Comment: @Amy This page has lot of other fields.i just took only the field has problem .first validation to select atleast one checkbox working fine .

Comment: @Rajesh
i tried with all 3 options innerHtml,innerText,value

Comment: @epascarello  first validation validation is working fine .

Comment: @kumarjcet NOT with the code you posted. lol, it is missing a closing " so the snipplet throws an error.....

Answer (score 3):

You can use 
**getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;** instead of getElementsByTagName("input");

For Example 
Try it

```
<input type="text"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
                       alert(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
                       }
</script>
```

Comment: @Ravikant   var CHKcblProcess = document.getElementById("<%=cblProcess.ClientID%>");
            var checkboxProcess = CHKcblProcess.getElementsByTagName("input"); for (var i = 0; i < checkboxProcess.length; i++)
            {               
                if (checkboxProcess[i].checked)
                {
                    alert(document.checkboxProcess[i].value);
                                   counter++;                    
                }
            }

Comment: I have given an idea to user to get value form single input field.Generally if we write code document.getElementsByTagName("input"),It shows undefined.