# How to fix loop to check if checkbox is checked, and if so append value to string?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, checkbox, field

Can't get loop to spit out a string of the values in checked checkboxes.

Basic Javascript.

I've tried to follow various other stackoverflow posts to no avail. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599666/get-the-value-of-checked-checkbox) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements) seemed to be what was closest to what I'm trying to make work.

The HTML is just a row of

```html
<div class="help-days">MON<br><input type="checkbox" id="d0-field" value="Monday" aria-describedby="avail-help"></div>
```

I've tried

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('help-days');
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (element[i].checked) {
        var day = $('#d' + i + '-field').val();
        days = days + ' ' + day;
    }
}
```

and

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById('#d' + i + '-field')
    if (element[i].checked) {
        var day = $('#d' + i + '-field').val();
        days = days + ' ' + day;
    }
}
```

Below example outputs `Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday` which leads me to believe there's something about using HTMLCollection and for loops & checking checkboxes that I'm not quite grasping?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    var day = $('#d' + i + '-field').val();
    if (day) {
        days = days + ' ' + day;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a string that appends a checkbox 'value' to the string, if the checkbox is checked.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include the `#` character when you use `document.getElementById`. The `#` character is used with JQuery

And you don't need to write `element[i].checked`, only `element.checked` because `element` is already a reference to your checkbox element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var element = document.getElementById('d' + i + '-field')

  if (element.checked) {
    var day = element.value
    days += ' ' + day;
  }
}
```

Comment: After missing around with it a bit more, I got it to work. My original method with ID was fine, the # broke everything from what I can tell though. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('help-days');` this will return the list of `div`s, and they don't have a `checked` property, you'll need to select the checkboxes inside of them :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var checkbox = element[i].childNodes[2];

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        var day = $('#d' + i + '-field').val();
        days = days + ' ' + day;
    }
}
```

```js
var days = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var element = document.getElementById('d' + i + '-field')

  if (element.checked) {
    var day = element.value
    days += ' ' + day;
  }
}

console.log(days)
```

```html
<div class="help-days">MON<br><input type="checkbox" id="d0-field" value="Monday" aria-describedby="avail-help" checked></div>
<div class="help-days">TUE<br><input type="checkbox" id="d1-field" value="Tuesday" aria-describedby="avail-help" checked></div>
<div class="help-days">WED<br><input type="checkbox" id="d2-field" value="Wednesday" aria-describedby="avail-help"></div>
```

Comment: Tried it this way, same result as on my own, simply no output nor errors. Thanks though.