# How to get checked value using javascript and razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor page with a table, in the table there is a checkbox in each row which holds the ID value of the row item.

I am trying to send the ID value of the currently checked box to a method I have on my index page using Ajax. The Ajax method is working okay, but when I debug I can see the ID value is not being set properly. The Guid is just a list of zeros in a Guid format.

Here is the page containing my JS:

```
@model IList<Project>


@using AttackSurfaceReview.ASRData.Model;
@using AttackSurfaceReview.Areas.Identity.Data;
@using AttackSurfaceReview.Services
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines

@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
@inject IProjectSelector selector
@inject IASRUserService userService
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf

@{
}

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@*
    Add a search box here - not essential but would be nice
*@
<form method="post"></form>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].CreationDate)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].ProjectName)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Company Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Owner
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].DueDate)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].IsActiveProject)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @item.CompanyName()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @userService.GetUsernameAsync(@item.OwnerId)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)
                            </td>
                            <td id="CheckedProject" value="@item.Id">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActiveProject)
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input type="hidden" id="clientSideActiveId" runat="server" />
            @*when user clicks this button the app should set the current project to the sleected project in the <select> statement above*@
            <button id="saveButton" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
@*Write a script here which only allows one clientSideActiveProject checkbox to be active at a time and uncheck any other checkbox which may be ticked*@
@*Set the clicked ID to the ID of the project at the currently clicked checkbox*@
    <script>
        // Get all the checkboxes
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#CheckedProject input[type=checkbox]");

        // Attach a click event handler to each checkbox
        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
                // Uncheck all the checkboxes
                checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
                    checkbox.checked = false;
                });

                // Check the clicked checkbox
                this.checked = true;
            });
        });
    </script>
    @*write a script which uses the IProject selector service to set the active project when the save button is clicked. The active project is determined by the checkbox which is currently checked*@
    <script>
        // Attach a click event handler to the button
        document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Get the selected project from the dropdown
        var selectedProjectId = $('#CheckedProject:checked').val();

            // Send an AJAX request to set the active project
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // Use POST or GET depending on your API endpoint
                url: "/Index?handler=ChangeProject", // Replace with your controller and action names
                data: { projectId: selectedProjectId },
                headers: {
                    "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Note: Only one checkbox can be checked at a time, I have written JavaScript to uncheck all he other checkbox when the user clicks a new checkbox.

I have tried every suggestion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599666/get-the-value-of-checked-checkbox) post.

This is the method which takes the incoming ID:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangeProject(Guid project)
        {
            await projectSelector.SetActiveProject(project);
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
```

Here is what I see when i debug:

[image]

Comment: Ohh my form - this is just to initialize my CSRF token. I am passing the value in the AJAX request

Comment: Hi, this `$('#CheckedProject:checked').val();` line doesn't seems proper as  `CheckedProject` is your td tag . Instead change that to `$('#CheckedProject input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();`

Comment: Hi @LiamWBA, any updated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The `value` should be set in the checkbox:

```
<td id="CheckedProject">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActiveProject,new{value=@item.Id})
<td>
```

2.Get the checkbox value by js like below:

```
var selectedProjectId = $('#CheckedProject input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
```

3.The passed name in ajax `data` should match with the parameter name in action.
The data you pass with name `projectId`:

```
data: { projectId: selectedProjectId },
```

so the parameter here should also be named `projectId`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangeProject(Guid projectId)
```

4.The contentType should not be `application/json; charset=utf-8"`, it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or you can just remove this line:`// contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`.

Comment: Amzing, worked a charm. Please can you explain this bit to me `new{value=@item.Id}`, or link me the documentation for this please?

Comment: Hi @LiamWBA, you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12674731/11398810).